# Weird vertices after sculpting, what caused this and how to fix?

Tags: sculpting

After sculpting for some time I noticed those weird duplicated faces had appeared and I don't know when this happened so I can't go back, there is a way to fix it?[image: sculpt mode]

[image: edit mode]

Answer (score 1):

If the faces are some kind of underlying duplicate mesh, in Edit Mode hover over your mesh and hit **L** to select linked faces and see if it is a seperate mesh that can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press "A" twice to select all the faces in Edit mode and then press "W"-"remove doubles". Maybe it can help.